# Windows Phone 8 StaticResource Styles

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to find where the Static Resource Styles are declared in any new WP8 application.

```
<TextBlock Text="Delaware" Margin="1,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
```

For example, I cannot locate the resource "PhoneTextTitle1Style" anywhere in my project.  I have also tried searching through the Design folder of the WP8 sdk to no avail.  It would be nice to find out this information is clearly documented somewhere by MS.  Perhaps it is and I've overlooked, but none of my searches have turned up anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the phone theme resources are located at:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx

These are the predefined styles available to all Windows Phone applications. You don't need to include any specific ResourceDictionary's, or define them youself.